# KML relative URL warning

Tags: kml, relative-path

I have this little piece of KML code which shows an image when clicked on the placemark, all images i have are store locally, and it works fine when using the .kml file it self.
Once the file is compressed into .kmz i'll get a warning (yellow marked) on the first line of the CDATA, covering some of my text.

It says: "This balloon may be using incorrectly formatted image URL"

[image]
[image]

All of my images works fine, they are not missing, and the relative URL is correct, but the syntax is not.

Anyone out there know of a solution to get rid of that hardcoded message ? or even better how to "tune" the code, so this warnings don't show :)

I've seen a couple of examples, stating it should help, but none suits my need, unfortunally.

This was some of the solutions i've looked at, but still not got it working.

```
Option 1: Fix the URLs
Your base URL is one directory down from where you thought it was, so you can simply add “../” to the beginning of each offending relative URL. This works fine in earlier versions of Google Earth as well, because older versions will look in both directories (and as a bonus, your content will render faster in older versions).
To fix the above example, we’d change:
<img src="images/image.png”>
to
<img src="../images/image.png">

Option 2: Add a <base> tag
As with any other browser, you can add a <base> tag to your HTML to set the base URL of that content. The href parameter of the <base> tag must be an absolute URL, so you’ll have to hard-code your server name and path. Adding the <base> tag to your BalloonStyle can fix all of your URLs in one go.

To fix the above example, we’d add: <base href="http://host.example.com/kmz/somelayer/"> to the BalloonStyle (or description, if we only have a few affected placemarks).

Option 3: Move the files
If you can’t change the balloon content, you can still correct it by moving the resources it points to into the correct locations. Depending on the URL, there are a couple of ways to do this. In our example, you’d move or copy the “images” folder and its contents to the KMZ archive. If the offending URL was “../files/another_image.png” (which should have been “../../files/another_image.png”), you could move or copy the files folder into the somelayer folder to fix the problem.

In many cases, though, there will be many layers all referencing the files folder, so moving the files folder into each layer folder can get tedious. If you have access to the web server configuration, you can solve this by adding an HTTP redirect from each incorrect location that redirects up a directory. You could also move the KMZ file up a directory, but this will change the URL that people must use to access your KMZ file.
```

Comment: Post your KML code so that we can take a look at the structure.

Comment: The code snippet i've allready postet is the exact code that handles the placemark, which holds the image information, that recieves the warning...

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to look at your KML to see if it was properly formatted and test it on my end.